# Creating a method with a decimal parameter that goes from 0 to 1

Tags: c#, parameters, decimal, parameter-passing

Is it posible to create a method with a decimal argument, that only accepts values from 0 to 1?

Example:

```
public decimal GetSamplingError(decimal percent){

    decimal result = 0;

    result = 100*percent;

    return result;

}
```

is it posible to control that the parameter percent is compres between 0 and 1?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: thanks guys, Tigran answer seems good to me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create my own type of `Percent` with range checks as others have suggested and some additional stuff. That way, `Percent` is its own entity in your application and everyone knows when and how to use it. A plain decimal might work as well, I prefer the typed approach however.

```
 internal class Percent
    {
        private readonly decimal _value;
        public decimal Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
        }
        public Percent(decimal value)
        {
            _value = (100 * value);
            if (value < 0m || value > 1m)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
            }
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}%", _value);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            // HashCode implementation;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            // Equals implementation;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You _could_ consider making `Percent` a struct instead of a class. Not that it's wrong to make a class, but _if_ you choose to make a struct, you might not have to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` since `ValueType.GetHashCode` and `ValueType.Equals` which a struct inherits, are probably good enough.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I  thought about it and decided against :p. Thing is that ValueType.Equals uses reflection to compare each field which is generally slower than your own implementation. Also, Equals(obj) boxes your structs. Of course if you never call those methods it doesn't matter.

Comment: I hear you. It would probably be worth it to write your own `Equals` and `GetHashCode` then. If it's a struct, implement `IEquatable<Percent>`; that will avoid boxing with most new collection types (that use `EqualityComparer<Percent>.Default`).

Comment: Yes, thats true in case you're comparing items in a List<T>.

Comment: It's true quite generally with "strong" types. When there are two overloads `Equals(object)` and `Equals(Percent)` the latter will be preferred when you come with an argument of type `Percent`. If you have `x.Equals(y)` and `x` and `y` are `Percent`, and neither is boxed already (i.e. compile-time type of `x` and `y` is also `Percent`), the good overload will be called. If `y` is a box, the overload `Equals(object)` will apply compile-time, but `y` is already a box, and the same box is reused. I think it's worst if `x` is a box (compile-time type `object`, say), then `y` might be boxed also.

Answer (score 4):

no there is no way to control parameter's range, what you can do, is control it inside the function itself, and add a comment to the function

```
public decimal GetSamplingError(decimal percent){

     if(percent > 1) 
        percent = 1; 
     else if(percent <0) 
        percent = 0;

    return 100*percent;    
}
```

Or raise an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in case if the parameter is not in dsired range, but it depends on how you would like to manage a **worklfow** of your application.

Comment: +1 for ArgumentOutOfRangeException, better than my answer of ArgumentException.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of compile-time checking this. The best solution would be to check the argument at run-time:

```
public decimal GetSamplingError(decimal percent)
{
    if (percent < 0m || percent > 1m)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Percent should be between 0 and 1!", "percent");
    }

    decimal result = 0;
    result = 100*percent;
    return result;
}
```

Other than the approach of Tigran, this will throw an Exception when an invalid argument is passed. I prefer this method over just changing the percent-value, becasue it'll actually make you notice that you passed a wrong value.

When you use `Code Contracts` of Microsoft, then you could add a contract that ensures that the value is in a specific range. When static checking is enabled, you'll get an error message at `compile-time`.

```
Contract.Requires(percent > 0m && percent < 1m, "Percent must be between 0 and 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do:

```
public decimal GetSamplingError(decimal percent){
    if (percent < 0m || percent > 1m)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("percent", "Must be between 0 and 1.");

    // rest of method
}
```

Of course, it is also possible to make your own `struct` called `DecimalBetweenZeroAndOne` which is immutable and holds a decimal field which is `readonly` and where you write a check to guarantee that the value of the field is always in the required range.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to validate the input and throw exception if value is not what you expected:

```
    decimal getPercentage(decimal val)
    {
        if (val < 0 || val > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        return val * 100;
    }
```